# JAVASCRIPT: What is shortest most cryptic way to write this indexof check for mulitple chars?

Tags: javascript

What is the shortest most cryptic way to write out the following code? This code checks if chars exist before proceeding.

```
if(window.location.href.toString().indexOf('A') > 1) {

if(window.location.href.toString().indexOf('hh') > 1) {

if(window.location.href.toString().indexOf('eg3') > 1) {

if(window.location.href.toString().indexOf('1g4') > 1) {

}

}

}

}
```

Comment: Well for starters you can declare a variable to hold `window.location.href.toString()` instead of repeating the method call, and combine all of those `if` statements into one using `&&`.

Comment: Are you deliberately ignoring cases where any of those strings occur in the first two characters of the href?

Comment: What do you mean by "most cryptic"? Are you trying to obfuscate the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this more or less cryptic line?

`function check (a,b) {for (var i=0,k,f=1;k=b[i];i++) {f^=!!~a.indexOf(k)};return !f;}`

Or if you prefer, the [Closure compiled version](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)

`function check(d,e){for(var b=0,c,a=1;c=e[b];b++)a^=!!~d.indexOf(c);return!a};`

Output

```
var x = "asdf";    
console.log("found: %s", check (x,["qwer","rtz"])) //found: false
console.log("found: %s", check (x,["qwer","a"])) //found: true
```

This checks for `a` containing any string contained in `b`

In your case
    `check (window.location.href,["A","hh","eg3","1g4"])?/*Code to execute when true*/:/*When false*/`

Or `(function (a,b) {for (var i=0,k,f=1;k=b[i];i++) {f^=!!~a.indexOf(k)};return !f;})(window.location.href,["A","hh","eg3","1g4"])?alert("found"):alert("not found")`

Comment: this is embarassing but how do you use the check function in an if then statement?

Comment: @Gast1 `if (check ("asd",["a"])) {//do stuff} else {//do other stuff}` or using a ternary operator `check("asd",["a"])?alert("true"):alert("false")`

Comment: is this right? if (check(window.location.href.toString(),["a"]) { //dostuff }   assuming the url has an a in it

Comment: @Gast1 a little `)` is missing. -> `if (check2(window.location.href.toString(),["a"])) { //dostuff }`. But yes if the url has an **lowercase** `"a"` in it `//dostuff` will be executed

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports `forEach()` method you could write in this cryptic way

```
var str = location.href,    
    existAllSubstring = 1; 

["A", "hh", "eg3", "ig4"].forEach(function(s) {
   existAllSubstring *= +(str.indexOf(s) > 1);
});


if (existAllSubstring > 0) {
  /* ok */
}
```